# computing gradients w.r.t classes in a keras classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am struggling with computing gradients w.r.t classes in the output layer of ANN classifier in keras (tf backend).
here's the model's architecture :

```py
model = Sequential([
  Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
  Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
])
```

and here's how i compute gradient :

```py
outputTensor = model.output
listOfVariableTensors = model.trainable_weights[4]
gradients = k.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)
evaluated_gradients[0].shape
```

I obtained (64,10) shape where I wanna get (784,10). I think the problem is in the list of variable tensors.

Comment: You need to better describe the gradient, you want gradient of classes, with respect to what variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the gradient of the output with respect to the input, this is actually the jacobian, gradients are defined for scalar functions, so you need to do:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.parallel_for.gradients import jacobian
gradients = jacobian(model.output, model.input)
```

This should have shape `(samples, 784, None, 10)`.

Comment: For some reason I get the shape (samples,784)

Comment: I get (samples,784,samples,10) instead of (samples,784,10)

Comment: @EssounainiAnas What is the actual value you get? Print it from the terminal

Comment: solved the problem you can check my answer below. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```py
def jacobian_tensorflow(x,M=10):    
    jacobian_matrix = []
    for m in range(M):
        # We iterate over the M elements of the output vector
        grad_func = tf.gradients(model.output[:, m], model.input)
        gradients = sess.run(grad_func, feed_dict={model.input: x.reshape((1, x.size))})
        jacobian_matrix.append(gradients[0][0,:])

    return np.array(jacobian_matrix)
```

Thanks everyone